# Elastic Search, delete_by_query takes a long time to finish and causes http request to timeout

Tags: elasticsearch

The deletion is still working but the server throws exceptions because it takes too long. What's the best way to handle this on the server side?

The [delete_by_query api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-task-api) doc says it will return a task so I can track the deletion progress.

*If the request contains wait_for_completion=false then Elasticsearch will perform some preflight checks, launch the request, and then return a task which can be used with Tasks APIs to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch will also create a record of this task as a document at .tasks/task/${taskId}. This is yours to keep or remove as you see fit. When you are done with it, delete it so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space it uses.*

How to get this task id? It's not in the HTTP response, also in the timeout scenario, there may not even be an HTTP response.

`GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*/delete/byquery` will return me a list of deletion tasks but I just want the one task. If there are two tasking running, how would I know which is the one I am looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Elasticsearch 6

Create task:

```
nick@work:
curl -X POST "es-prices-ape:9200/prices /_delete_by_query?wait_for_completion=false" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cella_id": "58259"
    }
  }
}
'

{"task":"GChf5jO9Q2Sti-Qi1G-oAw:12221137"}
```

Get task info:

```
nick@nick-home:~$ curl -X GET "es-prices-ape:9200/_tasks/{GChf5jO9Q2Sti-Qi1G-oAw:12221137}"

{"completed":true,"task":{"node":"GChf5jO9Q2Sti-Qi1G-oAw","id":12221137,"type":"transport","action":"indices:data/write/delete/byquery","status":{
"total" : 0,
"updated" : 0,
"created" : 0,
"deleted" : 0,
"batches" : 0,
"version_conflicts" : 0,
"noops" : 0,
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with `wait_for_completion=false`. It also works fine on ES 5.5